# Cannot scale down CosmosDB Collection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have 4 collections in a CosmosDB and I have scaled down to 400RUs 3 of them but the 4th I cannot scale down. I can put 400RUs in the portal but the Save button wont activate. Why? How can I scale down my collection? The minimum it says it is 1000 RUs.

[image: Image from Azure Portal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with what @David Makogon says. Combine with the guidance on the portal when we create collections, we can't set RUs less than `1000` if we create unlimited partitioned collection.

[image]

I tested some different situations.

***Test1:***

I created unlimited partitioned collection successfully with `1000` RUs. Then I found the range of throughout is `400-10000` RUs.

[image]

I scaled down the throughout to `400` RUs and it can be saved.Also, the stroage capacity changed to Fixed with it as same as you. Fully demonstrate the scalability of Cosmos db.

***Test 2:***

I noticed that the range of throughout is `1000-50000` RUs in your screenshot. So I created a new unlimited partitioned collection successfully with `1100` RUs. And it can't scaled down to `400` later.

[image]

I think that's the reason though I can't find any official explanations related to this. So you could refer to my test conclusion that if you set throughout larger than `1000` RUs when you create an **unlimited** collection, then you can't scale down it less than `1000` RUs later.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: `So you could refer to my test conclusion that if you set throughout larger than 1000 RUs when you create collections, then you can't scale down it less than 1000 RUs later.` - Jay I think your conclusion is somewhat incorrect. Essentially it boils down to collection size. A fixed size collection (10 GB) can have a minimum RU of 400 (it can be partitioned). However an unlimited size collection can have a minimum of 1000RUs. The key here is the size of the collection that you specify at the time of collection creation.

Comment: @GauravMantri Hi,Gaurav. Based on the official doc,just like you said: an unlimited size collection can have a minimum of 1000RUs. However , after my test, I did find that when I set the 1000RUs unlimited collection.It can be scaled down to 400RUs on the portal. I'm not sure whether it's a bug.Maybe you could tested on the portal.

Comment: @GauravMantri If I set larger than 1000 RUS unlimited collection at the time of collection creation, It completely follows rules that can't be less than 1000 RUS.

Comment: Probably a bug I will migrate the existing to a new unlimited and try to scale down from there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to scale down a partitioned collection (the giveaway is the presence of a partition key), which starts at 1000 RU.

Only single-partition (10GB) collections go down to 400 RU.

Comment: All the other collections are partitioned as well. As soon as I put 400 RUs they change to Fixed and let me save. Is there something I could do to this one?